# Detect HTML tags in textarea/text input with javascript, but it should supports the common > and <

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna to detect the the html tags in textarea or text input before submitting a form, it looks easy to do the detection "roughly" with regular expression `/<\/?[^>]*>/gi.test(str)`

But if there are some normal content like "**This clothes is not suitable for me since my height < 180cm and > 170cm**", the previous regExp will consider this content contains html tags coz there are `<` and `>`..

So, how to detect the html tags while supporting the normal greater-than and less-than sign?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the * in you Expression to a Plus: `/<\/?[^>]+>/gi`

- `*` Means 0 or 1 of the pre Token
- `+` Means 1 or more

And a HTML tag always has at least one char in the tag.

Comment: uh, Thanks so much. But it doesn't work when the content like "height < 180cm, and > 170cm". `/<\/?[^>]+>/gi.test('height < 180cm, and > 170cm')`

Comment: With this Expression: `<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>` you can match Phrases like `<html>xxx</html>`. It doesent work with Tags like <br/> or with Tags nested in themself. The Text between the Tags is Captured in the 2. Group, if you want to get that substring.

Comment: If you want to validate/sanitize your String to avoid Spam. I would recommend you to use a Server site method like [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php) in PHP, becouse ist a lot more safe. Post data can be send without even go through your Client side script.